# Android: Relative layout layout

Tags: android

I'm doing this fill-out questions about BMI and I wanna do this in a relative layout inside a linear layout. I don't have a testing device for this so I'm just relying on the graphical layout of the eclipse.

[image]

The 0.0 on the right of the height is the bmi itself I'm just going to put below the weight then after the BMI I'm going to put a dynamic textview then the compute button. Can anyone help?

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayoutbmi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#009900">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributeheight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/height"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextHeightft"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="75dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewattributeheight"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributeheightft"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edittextHeightft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/feet"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextHeightinch"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textviewattributeheightinch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittextHeightft"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributeheightinch"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edittextHeightinch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textviewattributeheightft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/inch"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributeweight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/weight"/>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextWeight"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewattributeweight"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittextHeightinch"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|number"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributeweightlbs"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edittextweight"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textviewattributeheightft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lbs"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewattributebmi"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textviewattributeweight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/bmi"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewBMI"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewattributebmi"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edittextWeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textviewBMIDescription"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewBMI"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textviewattributeweightlbs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/buttonComputeBMI"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textviewBMI"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/compute"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your code first ,how you tried so far?

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` is useless because its only child is a `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

after creating text view dynamically add this code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) bookmark.getLayoutParams(); 
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.where_you_want);
textview.setLayoutParams(params);
```